# RAID 5 to 2x RAID 1

Tags: raid, raid5, raid1

Is it possible to convert RAID 5 to 2x RAID 1 without any data loss?
Example: 
3x 1TB HD in RAID 5 + 1x 1TB like Hot Spare
convert to
2x 1TB RAID 1 + 2x 1TB RAID 1

Comment: Yes.  Backup all the data, destroy the RAID-5 and make two RAID-1s, restore the data.  But  can you do it *in situ*?  No: one of the current data discs is going to turn into a mirror disc.

Comment: This would kind of depend on the controller, or the OS if a software RAID.  If software RAID, and a bit of bravery and foolhardyness you could probably remove the hotspare, and one of the disks from the RAID5.  With those removed you could set those up as two RAID1 volumes with a 'missing' second drive.  Then transfer  your data.  After you have transferred from the data remove the RAID5 and add the two remaining members to the two RAID1 volumes.  You need a backup in place.

Comment: Thx for the answer. So, I was wrong that this is possible. The only way is a backup like you said and then restore. One more question related to RAID.  Current configuration is present 2x RAID 1 in RAID BIOS..... If I remove the configuration from RAID BIOS and recreate the same configuration.....this action will wipe all data from hd's? Correct?

Comment: It is LSI MegaRAID card.

Comment: @Zoredache points for you, I missed that the current four disc setup is a 3-disc RAID-5 and a hot spare, rather than a 4-disc RAID-5.  That does make it theoretically possible, assuming a controller as bright as Linux software RAID (which very few are) - but you are dead right that a backup is still a must-have.

Comment: I test it....all data was erased.